# Android best practice to validate form that uses an API, app side or server side?

Tags: android, django, api, validation

I'm here again with a new question about android and I hope that experts helps me with this question to keep improving my abilities.

I'm using retrofit to make an app that connects to an API to add new content, I do that with a form in my app and this forms requires validations, at this moment I implemented the validators inside my app and displays the errors with setError() and requestFocus(), all this on app side.

From my API backend I'm using Django with Django Rest Framework, and with that I'm making my forms and my serializers, the advantage of using this is that if I post not valid data it returns me as response a json with each field and it's errors on a list, something like this:

```
  {
    "errors": {
        "password": [
            "Required field."
        ],
        "email": [
            "Required field."
        ]
    },
    "error": true
}
```

My question in this case is, What is the best practice to handle the validators of my form to post the information? Completely from the app(empty field or invalid format), or using that response from the API which contains the information of server side validation?

I hope this is not a bad question, I'm just trying to learn which one is the best solutions an their pros an cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**API-Based Validation**

**Pros:** Using the validation from the API makes it easier to maintain because if some other front end app consume it, you don't need to re-do the validation again, also it is much secure because front end validation can be bypassed by direct calling the API using tools (postman, etc)

**Cons:** API based validation is not real-time because you need to call the API before to know if the input is valid or not, it will be hassle to the user if he/she is done filling up the form and by the time he/she submits, there's wrong with the info he/she inputs, and repeat/update it again.

**In-App Validation**

**Pros:** In-App validation can be real-time, and it can tell the user that his/her input is not valid as soon as he/she types them. The user can skip the hassle filling the form with the wrong info and wait for the submission just to know that his/her input is wrong and repeat it again.

**Cons:** You can read the cons on the pros of API, you must do this again and again each time you make another app that consumes the same API and also, it is not that secure when the API is directly called. (The hacker can input anything he/she wants).

**Conclusion:** As for my experience, the API must always have a validation to avoid hackers directly input anything on it, and it is up to the front-end app if he/she wants to use the validation on the API side OR he/she can make it on front-end itself to be real-time.